# Things to see by bicycle in the Camargue

Tags: france, nature-and-wildlife, bicycles, scenic-routes

I am going on a 3-day 2-night easy cycling trip in the [Camargue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camargue) (Rhône river delta) at the end of August.  I am looking for advice to help me plan a good route, in particular suggestion for places to go to or paths to cycle.

My primary criteria are (in no particular order):

- I am looking to see nature and wildlife (birds)
- Safety: Less car traffic is always better.
- Access: At some point I want to get off the paved road.  I don't know where this is possible.  I expect most areas to be farmland or fenced private areas.  I have been there once before with friends and walked on dirt paths by dry lakebeds. But I don't know where these places were as I didn't drive or plan the route.
- Side roads with pleasant views are preferable, dirt roads are okay.

Let me explain better why I am asking for advice here.  I am used to biking in the Dombes region of Ain.   There are hundreds of small ponds and lots of waterfowl.  But it took me several trips there before I found where the interesting and accessible areas were.  Google Maps doesn't help in deciding what is *accessible*.  Street view isn't usually available on small dirt roads.  The local tourist office had a map with a suggested biking path, but this path was mostly passing by ponds which were fenced private area and often hidden from view by thick hedging.   If you asked me where to go in the Dombes, I could give very specific suggestions which are different from the local tourist map.

I won't have much time to explore in the Camargue, so I am trying to plan a good route in advance.  I will have to get to the destination (hotel) each day before sunset.

Given the popularity of performance cycling I want to make it clear that we don't care about "performance", nor are we in excellent shape. We want to take it easy, see interesting things and take nice photos.  Cycling is a *means* to see the region and not a goal in itself.  We have no driver's license and will bring our own bikes by train.

Comment: Close voters: Is this something that would usually be handled by a travel agent?